# Floating thumbnails with :nth-child CSS skipping a column

Tags: css

I have a gallery of floated thumbnails which I'd like flush against both sides of the containing div, but with whitespace between them.

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sakahane/UHN4A/) of the desired behaviour.

Relevant CSS:

```
.thumb {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: calc((100% - 72px)/3);
  margin-top: 18px;
  margin-right: 36px;
  transition: opacity 750ms ease-in-out;
  }

    @media screen and (max-width: 1553px) {

      .thumb:nth-child(3n+3) {
        margin-right: 0;
        }

    }

    @media screen and (min-width: 1554px) and (max-width: 2059px) {

      .thumb {
        width: calc((100% - 108px)/4);
        }

      .thumb:nth-child(4n+4) {
        margin-right: 0;
        }

      }

    @media screen and (min-width: 2060px) {

      .thumb {
        width: calc((100% - 144px)/5);
        }

      .thumb:nth-child(5n+5) {
        margin-right: 0;
        }

      }
```

In Chrome and Firefox on OSX, at some resolutions (such as 1024px), the thirteenth thumbnail centres itself in the container and puts all the :nth-child styles out of whack, breaking the layout below. I've changed the order of the thumbnails, but it's always the thirteenth one. Thinking it may have something to do with fractions of pixels resulting from the calc() division, I subtracted 1px from the width of the thumbnails, with no luck either.

I don't see any relevant difference between what I've done in the JSfiddle and the WIP site. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: These media quaries should work, I think.

Comment: Apologies. The bug had nothing to do with the CSS. Some of the images were 1px taller than the others.

Answer (score 0):

Well it's not your real answer, but i think you are getting hard to your self!
There are very cool and easy ways to create what you want.
I recommend you to read more about [`Foundation Block Grid`](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/block_grid.html) and [`FlexBox`](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).
don't try to reinvent the wheel.